# Linux installer won't install Virtual-Box for Debian-Stretch

Tags: linux, virtualbox, installation, chromebook, debian-stretch

I'm not good at Linux things, so I haven't done much. I also don't have an actual Linux computer, I just use  Chromebook to get Linux-Only things. But when I get VirtualBox 6.1 for Debian-Stretch, it says it failed to install, so I look at the details and it says: Error while installing package: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135. Does anyone know how to help? I've only reinstalled the file so if there's anything else please help me!

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to install VirtualBox _inside_ the ChromeOS Linux VM?

Comment: Yeah, the Linux terminal on Chrome OS otherwise referred to as the Linux VM that isn’t really a good VM!